# Why do we say earth has zero eletric potential? Why is this useful?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, earth, conventions

Why do we say earth has zero electric potential?

How can this be useful for us? What are the applications of this assumption?

It's more intuitive to me to think about  gravitational potential energy. Talking about Eletrical Potential is harder to understand.

Comment: Usually boundary conditions are chosen for convenience and free to choose up to some gauge. I usually had stuff like continuous derivatives and is bounded when the distance goes to infinity. What context was it set to zero in? (Earth as in grounded?)

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with earthing a circuit and it is not entirely accurate. There are stray currents in the earth that can develop naturally or can be leaked or impressed in to the soil. Pipeline companies impress direct current into the soil from anodes to complete a circuit with the pipe to prevent corrosion.

Natural currents can develop from storm clouds or dust passing over the ground that has a different potential to the ground below.

It is useful to have a path to earth for unintentional shorted circuits, an electron sink for alternating current. If you observe a circuit breaker panel (and I recall correctly) in a home you will see that the white wire is connected to the ground. As long as all the power sockets, switches and appliances are wired correctly this is not a problem. The black wire is live, the white is neutral and the green is ground. The ground is there to protect the users, the black supplies the alternating current and the white is the other end of the rope. The way I understand it, you can consider the electric current in a wire like an incompressable rope. With DC current it pushes through to do the work, but with AC it pushes and pulls. If the white were not connected to the ground you would not have any electrons to pull into the wire. This is the way I visualize it and it is not perfect but it helps me comprehend what is going on, I see it like the rope is passing through an incandescent light bulb creating friction as it goes that makes the light.

I hope this helps.

Drew K

Comment: Yes, I liked your answer. I still got a lot of common sense doubts about this. Per example, I saw that earth potential was a big negative number. If we consider DC current, wouldn't the earth push the current? Since the real direction of motion of current is from the negative terminal to the positive?

Comment: Re: "If the white were not connected to the ground you would not have any electrons to pull into the wire."  Not true.  AC circuits can be completely isolated from ground.  The current flows in a _loop_, from the transformer or generator, through the load, and back to the generator/transformer.  The fact that it changes direction is not a problem:  Current just flows in the other direction around the same loop. 
 The reason why the power grid is _not_ isolated from ground is mainly to prevent high voltages from building up on overhead lines due to atmospheric phenomena.

Comment: @jameslarge despite it isn't necessary to have something connected to the ground, on our electric circuit we keep needing a neutral, right? or the electric circuit goes like source->charges->source and we don't actually need a neutral? 
So, since Earth's potential related to infinity is very small, we use it as our referencial, because it is safer, and any high voltage goes to there?

Comment: @James Large, thank you for the clarification, I know my understand of EE is not as strong as I would like. I should have remembered the amount of electrons needed is relatively small and even if the wire were not connected it would just alternate from a positive to a negative state.

Comment: @vitor Aguiar, the only time I know the direction of electron travel is critical is with cathodic protection. They want the protected metal structure to be the cathode and the anode to be sacrificial. In this situation they want the electrons to flow to the pipe because if it were the opposite the anodic cells would endure rapid corrosion because the iron loosing electrons will bond with available oxygen or other available molecules. We had a year old pipeline start to  leak where 2 pipes cross just a few miles away because of this phenomenon.